# no delete vote for community?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, closed-questions

I was searching through site when I came upon this [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1644/4710). 
https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1644/4710

I'm sure everyone agrees that it's off topic by an extent that no edit can help it. But it's still around and even a mod also answered it. Please, being [closed] doesn't make it go out of access.

- But my Q is that, wouldn't it be good if also the community can vote for deletion?? at least  I can't see that option. Or we should just wait and see what mods would do, I guess?

pzl shed on some light here,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `delete` vote that is available only for high rep user. For Beta sites, you need 2k rep points in order to vote for delete. The question must be closed/on-hold for more than 48 hours for this option to be available. 3 delete votes are needed to delete the question. I believe moderator can delete posts on their own as we have seen a lot of posts have been deleted here by moderators.

[image]

Related
[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Comment: thanks, but 2k?? just to vote for delete? uhhh that explains why that post is still there after a whole year.